# How to force Windows 10 with multiple monitors always to open new apps on the monitor where is last click was performed

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

Hi folks: As you may notice when working on multiple monitors, windows 10 sometimes opens a new window on the opposite monitor than the monitor your currently working on (the monitor where you may double-click the new app). This is very handy in most cases. However, due to the Covid-19 pandemic, I often work via remote access (e.g. Teamviewer, AnyDesk). When I open a new Explorer window or a document, it is very inconvenient if my action is seemingly randomly performed on the other screen. I am thus forced to constantly switch the displayed screen with TeamViewer or AnyDesk back and forth.
Is there a way to set a new app to always open on the screen where the last click was performed?

So far, I have only found settings that cause apps to always open on the primary monitor. Is there a way to always open new apps on the active screen instead?

I also found this post. However, I have no Nvidia graphic cards
[How can I choose where new application windows open?](https://superuser.com/questions/323303/how-can-i-choose-where-new-application-windows-open)

This post describes several workarounds for a related issue on Windows-7 and Windows-8. Unfortunately, that is not what I am looking for.
[How to make applications open on the correct monitor when using multiple monitors?](https://superuser.com/questions/738081/how-to-make-applications-open-on-the-correct-monitor-when-using-multiple-monitor)

Comment: Programs have to comply with rules. This is the principal *To support this concept, applications should avoid automatically switching the user from one virtual desktop to another. Only the user should instigate that change. In order to support this, newly created windows should appear on the currently active virtual desktop. In addition, if an application can reuse currently active windows, it should only reuse windows if they are on the currently active virtual desktop. Otherwise, a new window should be created.*

Comment: From from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ivirtualdesktopmanager

Comment: the desktop is not virtual is actually physical. It seems that windows stacks the same application on the screen where is last windows of this particular application was opened. To avoid switch back and forth I have to drag the target application to my target screen. The next window of this application will open on the correct monitor